# Number Code - A Visitor by Moonlight

Tags: cipher

You hear a knock on the door downstairs while you're sleeping.
You creep down the stairs by the light of your phone, only to see a shadow exiting through the window.
By the moonlight, you see a piece of paper flutter down to the ground.
On it, is written: "If you can decrypt this by midnight tomorrow, perchance you may live."

> The following series of numbers and dashes is written:
>
> 131-123-122-333--121-333--333--322
>
> 122--113-113-131--113-233-212--222

Desperate to save your life, you get to work. **What is the solution you come up with?**